# Google Analytics for TCL-TK

Tags: google-analytics, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there any code for using Google Analytics on a TCL-Tk program?

I've tried to implement it "handmade" using a webserver, and sending messages via TclWs but I'm sure that Google Analytics can be a better (or best) solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/):

> The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make
>   HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google
>   Analytics servers. This allows developers to measure how users
>   interact with their business from almost any environment. Developers
>   can then use the Measurement Protocol to:
>
> - Measure user activity in new environments.
> - Tie online to offline
>     behavior.
> - Send data from both the web and server.
>
> > **Note:** The
> >     Measurement Protocol only allows developers to collect
> >     user-interaction (event / hit) data. It does not allow developers to
> >     upload aggregated data like tables.